# PHP: Wordpress update_user_meta not updating array correctly

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've been trying to figure out this issue with Wordpress update_user_meta and arrays.

This is what I currently have:

```
add_action('wp_login','user_last_logins', 0, 2);
function user_last_logins($login, $user) {  
    $user = get_user_by('login',$login);
    // Get the existing meta for 'meta_key'
    $meta = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_logins');
    // Do some defensive coding - if it's not an array, set it up
    if ( ! array($meta) ) {
        $meta = array();
    }
    $month = date('m');
    // Push a new value onto the array
    $meta[] = $month;
    // Write the user meta record with the new value in it
    update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_logins', $meta);
}
```

So everytime a user logs in, it should save the current month in an array in the database.

First login in database:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:2:"07";}
```

Second login in database:

```
a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:2:"07";}i:1;s:2:"07";}
```

As you can see it's saving the next login as an array within the previous one.

How can I get it to save to original array as or something similar:

```
a:2{
   i:0;s:2:"07", //First login
   i:1;s2:"07"   //Second login etc.
}
```

I've tried changing `$meta = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_logins');`
to `$meta = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_logins', true);`

But the update in the database saves over the previous array.

Really would appreciate the help!

UPDATE

Changing the below fixed the array issue

```
$meta = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_logins');
```

To

```
$meta = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_logins')[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `$meta = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_logins');` you get:

```
Array( [0] => Array ( [0] => 07 ) )
```

then you do `$meta[] = $month;` so you have now:

```
Array( [0] => Array ( [0] => '07' ), [1] => '07')
```

Since `get_user_meta()` is returning an array with an array inside, to append another value you should rather call: `$meta = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_logins')[0];`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried setting it to true but then I get an error `Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings`

Comment: OK, then I think `$meta = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_logins')[0];` could work, but I cannot check it now.